# Facet source not showing after upgrading to latest version

Tags: views

I recently updated one of our projects to Drupal 9.5.10 and facts to 3.x version. After updating to latest versions, facet source is not displaying and unable to add facet summary with existing views.
Previous Drupal version and facet versions are 9.3.6 and 8.x-1.8

After upgrading to latest version, getting below error when navigate to /search page

```
- The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
- Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "search_api:views_default__global_search__default" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\facets\FacetSource\FacetSourcePluginManager are: search_api:views_block__faq_listing__contextual, search_api:views_block__faq_listing__block_1 in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).
When I go to view edit page it showing "No facet source defined for facet." found and unable to save the view.
```

Please note that all facets, except the master display are showing in Facet source.
Not showing facets with default view.
[image]
Working with Previous Drupal version
[image]

How to show the facte source with views default display?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is reported as a bug on the project. It can’t be both a bug and an answerable question: https://www.drupal.org/project/facets/issues/3387096